# What does the ln or 1n mean in this equation?

Tags: education

What does the `ln` mean here?

[image: Equation]

It's from this page.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions

Finally, what could I have done to find out for myself? (What did I miss?) I know so little I can even tag the question!

---

Just because it might be useful for someone working on database identifiers, here's the code I ended up with.

```
    public static double HappyBirthday(double charCount, double keyLength = 9)
    {
        // Computes the number of IDs that would need to exist in a set
        // before there's a 50% chance of a collision.

        const double chanceOfCollision = 0.5;
        double spaceLength = Math.Pow(charCount, keyLength);

        var spacesConsumed = Math.Sqrt(2 * spaceLength * Math.Log(1 / (1 - chanceOfCollision)));

        return spacesConsumed;
    }
```

Comment: Natural logarithm. $\ln(x) \equiv \log_e (x)$

Comment: And to clarify, that is the letter $\ell$, not the number one.  Read more about logarithms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).  (*It is for that reason that $l$ and $1$ look so similar that you rarely see the variable $l$ used by itself written that way, using instead `\ell` $\ell$ or even if handwriting using $\ell\text{n}(x)$*)

Comment: Thanks. I feel the world would be a more math-literate place if math was communicated in a regular programming language.

Comment: Since you mention programming, it is worth pointing out that in some programming contexts and even combinatorial contexts it is sometimes possible that the author uses $\ln$ or $\log$ not as the natural base logarithm ("base $e$") or base-10 logarithm, but rather as the base-2 logarithm.  Knuth's Art of Computer Programming for example does this.  It doesn't really matter what base logarithm it is if referring to asymptotics and big-oh notation, but still it is worth confirming the notation for the specific context in which you are working.  The specific usage here was still base-$e$.

Comment: Thank you. Please add a proper answer and I can award it and close it off :)

Comment: I feel the world would be a more math-literate place if programmers actually studied math... :)

Comment: "Finally, what could I have done to find out for myself?" review a list of math notation like [this one by the Math Centre](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mccp-matthews-symbols.pdf), and/or search for something like "mathematical notation "ln"" in a search engine.

Comment: "Finally, what could I have done to find out for myself?" Alternatively, click "edit" on the Wikipedia page to see that the LaTeX/TeX command used was "\ln" and search for something like "\ln latex" in a search engine to find a page like [this tutorialspoint page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/ln.htm) which mentions it's the "natural logarithm symbol".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the natural logarithm. It is defined as
$$\ln x =\log_e x$$
Where $e$ is the Euler's number, defined as
$$e=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{k!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$ Sometimes l looks like $1$ in Calibri font.